# unmount google-drive-ocamlfuse

Tags: google-drive

I am trying to unmount google-drive-ocamlfuse. I entered the following command:

```
fusermount -u ~/google-drive
```

it returns:

```
fusermount: entry for /home/<user_name>/google-drive not found in /etc/mtab
```

What is wrong and how to fix it?

In general how can I uninstall `ocamlfuse`

Comment: Is it mounted in that location?

Comment: @MichaelBay, yes it was,  I mounted it using command: `google-drive-ocamlfuse ~/google-drive`. Whole my ubuntu is not very responsive now.

Comment: @MichaelBay, thank you for clarifying. How can I unmount it or remove it completely?

Comment: Try giving it the full path to where google-drive is actually mounted.

Comment: @MichaelBay full path is `/home/<user_name>/google-drive` and when I issue command with this path, I get back the same error

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have the same issue...

Comment: @smartmouse, Honestly, I do not remember now what I did ;-(

Answer (score 4):

Because you need mount folder first (in /home/user_name/google-drive):

```
# mount
google-drive-ocamlfuse ~/google-drive
```

An them umount:

```
# umount
fusermount -u ~/google-drive
```

PD: I recommend changing the name of the folder without symbols. Maybe "gdrive" or another similar

```
/home/user_name/gdrive
```

And it's even better to use a bash script described in the post [Share Google Drive in Samba](https://www.maravento.com/2018/11/compartir-google-drive-con-samba.html)

```
#!/bin/sh
# replace "user" with yout username unix account
MYUSER="user"
# replace "gdrive" with your (path) GoogleDrive Folder
GD="/home/$MYUSER/gdrive"

case "$1" in
  start)
    echo 'Mount Google Drive...'
    # Optional (If the folder does not exist)
    if [ ! -d $GD ]; then mkdir -p $GD && chmod 777 $GD; fi
    google-drive-ocamlfuse $GD
    echo "OK"
    exit
  ;;
  stop)
    echo 'Umount Google Drive...'
    fusermount -u $GD
    echo "OK"
    exit
  ;;
  *)
  echo "Usage: ./gdmu {start|stop}"
 exit 1
 ;;
 esac
 exit 0
```

Save as bash gdriveini (or any name you want) and execute (don't forget chmod +x gdriveini):

```
 ./gdriveini start
 ./gdriveini stop
```

Comment: This is not an answer. I have the same problem and I can't unmount the drive

Comment: @smartmouse Have you tried the solution? Keep in mind that this is a recurring problem with fuse, no matter the application that uses it. Sometimes it happens when we pass a file to the cloud and cancel the operation before finishing or sometimes for other reasons. The point is that this application (or any other one that uses fuse) is not very reliable

Comment: I have not dash or other symbols in the name of folder and I have just mounted and then tried to unmount the drive. I didn't any operation on files.

Comment: What message is displayed when you try to disassemble? (PD: please read this post https://www.maravento.com/2018/11/compartir-google-drive-con-samba.html)

Comment: What do you mean for "disasseble"? If you mean unmounting I get the same error described in the question. The post you linked is hard to use since the quoted commands are plenty of spaces!

Comment: Sorry for my english. Use script above to mount/unmount gdrive

Answer (score 0):

sudo rm -rf ~/.gdfuse

sudo rm -rf ~/your_google-drive